# Issue with TabBar icon color not changing when active in Expo using expo-router

Tags: react-native, tabs, icons, tabbar, expo-router

I'm using `expo-router` for navigation in my Expo app and encountering an issue with the TabBar where the icon color does not change when it's active. I've set up my `Tabs.Screen` components with specified `tabBarIcon` and `tabBarActiveTintColor` in the `screenOptions`, but the icon color remains the same whether it's active or inactive.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```js
import { Tabs } from "expo-router"
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";
export default () => {
    
    return (
      // <Stack>
      <Tabs
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "#FF6464",
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#000",
        }}
      >
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="EmergencyContacts"
          options={{
            tabBarIconStyle: { color: "#FF6464" },
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <AntDesign name="contacts" size={24} color="black" />
            ),
            title: "Contacts",
            headerTitleAlign: "center",
            headerTitle: "Emergency Contacts",
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#FF6464" },
            headerTintColor: "#fff",
          }}
        />
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="settings"
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <Feather name="settings" size={24} color="black" />
            ),
            title: "Settings",
            headerTitleAlign: "center",
            headerTitle: "Settings",
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#FF6464" },
            headerTintColor: "#fff",
          }}
        />
      </Tabs>
      // </Stack>
    );
}
```

I've tried specifying the `tabBarActiveTintColor` and `tabBarInactiveTintColor` within the `screenOptions`, and also styled the `tabBarIconStyle` separately, but the icon color doesn't change when the tab is active.

Any insights or suggestions on how to properly change the TabBar icon color when it's active using `expo-router` in Expo would be greatly appreciated!

I configured the screenOptions for the Tabs component, setting tabBarActiveTintColor to "#FF6464" and specifying tabBarIcon for each Tabs.Screen. Additionally, I experimented with tabBarIconStyle to modify the icon color based on the tab's activity.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have used static color in the **options** of **Tabs.Screen** component.

Have a try by changing code as below:

```
tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
    <AntDesign name="contacts" size={24} color={color} />
)
```

Comment: Oh, I see that the `color={color}` was set to `color="black"`, that's why it wasn't changing the color. Thank you so much!